# How to use OAuth 2 in Play Framework 2.0

Tags: java, scala, playframework

So I am using scribe to connect to Facebook (OAuth 2). However I am having trouble getting the authorization token. On [Play's website](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaOAuth) they say that

> "Version 2 is simple enough to be implemented easily without library or helpers,".

However, I'm not quite sure how to do this!

I tried changing my routes file that would send the key to a built method.

```
GET    /slivr_auth/*name        controllers.Application.getKey(name)
```

However, the auth key contains a '?' in the url, so I can't capture it as a string.

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: In case that helps, the author of the "Play Framework Essentials" book, Julien Richard-Foy, has included an [example](https://github.com/julienrf/pfe-samples/blob/ea59bd7/pfe-scala/oauth/app/controllers/oauth/OAuth.scala) in the github repo of the book. I haven't looked at it much as I opted to use Silhouette instead, but it may offer some good insights

Answer (score 4):

To answer your specific question, you can get request (query) parameters by calling:

```
Controller.request().queryString()
```

Getting OAuth2 is easy but not trivial. It helps to have a working sample. I would recommend downloading Play1, and looking up the sample for Facebook Authentication. And then porting the code over to Play2. I did the above and found the process very instructive. You will realize that each site and API has quirks/needs, so there is very little additional code that seems usable form one site to another.

A more step-by-step answer is that there are several steps. First, you need to get an `access_token` and then you can use it. To get an `access_token` you need to send the user to the sites authorization url, so far facebook this would be something like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=idFromFacebook&redirect_uri=http://yourdomain.com/auth
```

Once your user has accepted the authorization, the site will redirect the user with a code, something like `http://yourdomain.com/auth?code=XYZ_ABC`. You would then need to request from the sites access token url to get the access token. For Facebook this would be something like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=idFromFacebook&client_secret=secredFromFacebook&code=XYZ_ABC&redirect_uri=...
```

The response from the above url would have the `access_token` in it.

Now, you can start using the access token to request information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it might help, but I've created a Play 2.x client in Scala and Java which supports OAuth/CAS/OpenID/HTTP authentication and user profile retrieval : https://github.com/leleuj/play-pac4j.

For OAuth support, it's based on Scribe and supports Facebook, Twitter, Google, Yahoo, DropBox, Github, LinkedIn, Windows live, WordPress...